# Swift object has no member when it prints different

Tags: swift, object, member

I am implementing 3rd Party framework, trying to access members of object that I know they are there because when I print object I get

```swift
cardType: RTDFramework.CardType.itso(
        itsoCardType: RTDFramework.ITSOCardType.cmd7
    ), 
cardData: RTDFramework.ShellHeader(
        shellHeader: 32 bytes, 
        header: RTDFramework.Header(
            length: 6, bitMap: 1, formatRevision: 1
        ),
        isrn: 9 bytes,
.
.
```

but when I try to access it like `cardData.isrn` it says `CardData has no member isrn`
I looked into source code of framework, and I can kind of see why, because cardData is defined as a `CardData` class and that class is empty.
But why then data is return as `ShellHeader` and what can I do to access it ?

Comment: Can you post a link to the framework you're using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that the `ShellHeader` class is inheriting from the `CardData` class. Can you please try to cast `cardData` to `ShellHeader` using:

```swift
let shellHeader = cardData as? RTDFramework.ShellHeader
print(shellHeader?.isrn)
```